# Single or multiple rows for a flag?

Tags: database, database-design

On a system where users can have multiple settings, what would be the proper way of storing flags? All flags in a single row or have multiple rows?

Single row would be:

```
user_id       meta_key       meta_value
1             flags          000000
```

Where `000000` would be different states of different flags. Like, first bit for profile visibility, second bit for comments moderation, and so on.

Multiple rows would be:

```
user_id       meta_key       meta_value
1             flag_profile   0
1             flag_comments  0
1             flag_wall      0
[...]
```

There are many users and flags, and more flags may be added in the future, so having one column for each flag doesn't seem a good idea.

Comment: How are you storing your user settings that are *not* flags?

Comment: Multiple rows. Gotcha! Thanks.

Comment: How many users are you expecting, how many flags, and what is your primary concern ? Are you worrying about ease of use, storage needs, performance... ?